# Linear independence of an infinite set of functions

Tags: linear-algebra, independence

I came across this question in one of the linear algebra textbooks:

Proof the linear independence of the following set $\{f_i ∣ i\in\mathbb{N}\}$, such that $f_i : \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Q}$ defined as follows:

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $$f_i (n) =  
\begin{cases}
                   -n  & \text{for }n \geq i \\    
                    0  & \text{for }n < i \end{cases} $$

What would be an appropriate approach to check the independence of this infinite set? I thought long about it but was unable to come up with anything.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you have a read about [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and learn how to use it for your next question or answer!

Comment: Another approach you can try is viewing each function as an infinite vector  $v_i = ( f_i (1), f_i (2) , f_i (3), ...) $ in $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} $, and show that the $v_i $ are linearly independent  (this is more natural way to view it in my opinion).  For example, for $i=5$, $v_i = (0,0,0,0,-5,-6,-7 ...)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View each function as an infinite vector
$$v_i = \left( \begin{array}{c} f_i (1)\\ f_i (2) \\ f_i (3)\\ \vdots \end{array}\right) = \left( \begin{array}{c} 0\\0\\\vdots\\0\\-i\\ -i-1\\-i-2\\\vdots\end{array}\right)$$

in $\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{N} $, and show that the $v_i $ are linearly independent  (this is more natural way to view it in my opinion).  For example, for $i=5$, $v_i = (0,0,0,0,-5,-6,-7,...)$

Then  to check linear Independence, we check that the following is true only when all coefficients $a_i $ are zero:
$$ \sum_{i\geq 1} a_i v_i = \left( \begin{array}{c}
-a_1 \\
-2(a_1 + a_2) \\
-3 (a_1 + a_2 + a_3) \\
\vdots
\end{array}\right)
=
  \left( \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \end{array}\right)$$

But that's clear, since if we solve for the first entry we get $a_1 = 0$. Substituting that into the next entry we get $a_2 = 0$.  Continuing to infinity, we see that $$ a_i = 0 \qquad \mbox{ for all } i\geq 1$$

Comment: This is a nice solution. I like the viewing of each function as a vector. I see what you mean by $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ but I’m not sure that’s the best way of expressing that since we are raising a set to the power of a set...? We can raise a set to a power $\in \mathbb{N}$ by means of the Cartesian product, but what you wrote here seems kind of undefined.

Comment: It's actually pretty standard notation, but I agree you are right that not everyone may be familiar.  I will edit it in my answer.  The notation is for the space of functions mapping $X$ to $Y$, so $Y^X = \{ f:X\to Y \}$.  And there is a bijection  with the product space $\prod_{x\in X}Y$

Comment: Ah, okay. I’ve just never seen it before, but that’s my ignorance.

Comment: Thank you. That's the best written answer I got so far.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that in your class $0\notin \Bbb N$ (as otherwise the claim is clearly false).

Assume $\sum_i c_i f_i=0$ with almost all $c_i=0$.
For any $n>1$, we have 
$$ 0=\sum_i c_if_i(n)-\sum_i c_if_i(n-1)=\sum_i c_i(f_i(n)-f_i(n-1))=-nc_n,$$
hence $c_n=0$. Thus $0=\sum_i c_if_i(1)=c_1f_1(1)=-c_1$ and also $c_1=0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How did you arrive at −nc(n)?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the series

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \alpha_i f_i (n)$$ for scalars $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dots$.

We aim to prove that this series is never zero unless all scalars are zero.

First note that $\forall i \in \mathbb{N} \space \exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq i$. So $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \space $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i (n) \neq 0$ because all terms are either zero or negative and there exists a term where $n \geq i$ and so $f_i(n) = -n \neq 0$.
So the series cannot be zero by virtue of all of the function values being zero.

The only other way that this series could be zero is if some of the scalars $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dots$ are negative and so there is some cancellation in the terms. But since ($\forall i \in \mathbb{N} \space \exists j \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall k>j, j>i$), there are an infinite number of terms in the series less than any given nonzero term, so no matter how small a sum $f_i + f_{i+1} + f_{i+2} + \dots + f_{i+a}$ ($a \in \mathbb{N}$) is, there will always exist a term in the series that is less than this sum. In this way, we can never ‘cancel out’ all of the terms.

So $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \alpha_i f_i (n) \neq 0$ for scalars $a_1, a_2, \dots$ unless $\alpha_i = 0 \space \forall i \in \mathbb{N}$.

So the elements of $\{f_i | i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ are linearly independent since the only solution to this equation is where all of the scalars are zero.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's based on the assumption that all the scalars are positive?

Comment: Hmmm. That’s a good point. I think my proof may not fully work. Let me think about that...

Comment: I *believe* I have fixed it.

Comment: I get your point, but why are you adding the series till infinity? Wouldn't it suffice to just keep adding till a finite number to prove independence?

Comment: I don’t see why that would be the case. We have to consider all of the functions, of which there are an infinite number, don’t we?